# How to play MP3 url in AVaudioPlayer without loading buffer

Tags: swift

I'm trying to play in my app mp3 file from url ... But the problem is the **file size** is big 120 **MB** ... So i said why not making it load same as **youtube** since i heard we can control the buffer and not loading the full audio file to the player ... instead we can play small sizes same as youtube for example ... i search and tried to get a way or a code but i couldn't find anything.

So is it possible to play mp3 file using AVaudioPlayer **immediately** without loading the full audio file?

Answer (score 0):

Not with AVAudioPlayer. Use AVPlayer instead.